# Should the CoordinatorLayout be placed in the Activity or the Fragment when dealing with both scrolling and non-scrolling fragments?

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

In [the examples](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) for CoordinatorLayout, it's always placed in the Activity, and the Fragments are all scrolling.

It's reasonable to imagine a scenario though where some of the fragments being loaded are scrollable and some of the fragments are not, but they get loaded in the same placeholder in the activity. In this scenario, should the CoordinatorLayout be placed in the Activity or in the Fragments?

On one hand, because you specify the Toolbar as a child of it, it seems that it should all be in the Activity.

On the other hand, if you have both scrolling and non-scrolling fragments loaded in the same placeholder, then this seems difficult to configure (e.g. what scrolling behaviour do you specify for the Fragment placeholder?), so it seems like it should live in the Fragment. In that case though, does each Fragment have to set the Toolbar again?

Comment: Does this question relate to a specific problem? Because the answer depends on the situation. It's best if you manage to have the CoordinatorLayout and Toolbar in the Activity, but it might be difficult in some situations, that's true.

Comment: I've updated the question to make it more clear what the situation is that I am looking to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Q:should the CoordinatorLayout be placed in the Activity or in the Fragments?

A:You can use CoordinatorLayout in activity or fragment in different situation

Q:On one hand, because you specify the Toolbar as a child of it, it seems that it should all be in the Activity.

you can add toolbar to fragment layout instead of activity layout like below

in this example I create activity with NavigationView and viewPager :

so create layout for my activity(this layout is for MainActivity):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<FrameLayout

    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/tint_item_color"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/tint_item_color"
    />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

for create viewPager with tablayout I create this layout(this layout is for fragmentViewPager):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_main"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/tab_color"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/tab_color"

        />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

then use another layout for listFragment that I use in viewPager :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/main_list_content"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/background_window">



<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/exersice_listviwe"/>




<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_done"
    fab:layout_anchor="@+id/main_list_content"
    fab:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right"
    />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout >
```